# drop down sub category wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dropdown

hello i have sub category in wordpress

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Spesialisasi / Peminatan' ); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
        function onCatChange() {
            if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
                location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
            }
        }
        dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
        -->
    </script>
</li>
```

but i want display only sub category not category...please share if found fix :D
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get just the subcategories of a singular parent category, you can use the child_of arg:

```
wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'show_option_none' => 'Spesialisasi / Peminatan'
    'child_of' => 9
) );
```

This assumes that the parent of your sub categories has an ID of 9.

Alternatively, if you know the specific IDs of the categories you want (and they won't change), you can use the `id` and `exclude` args. Check out the WP docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

Answer (score 0):

thanks respon for me,,i use

```
<?php
```

$category=get_category_by_slug('dokter' );
?>

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories ( array(
    'hide_empty' => '0',
    'show_option_none'=>'Spesialisasi/Peminatan',
    'child_of'=>$category->term_id,
    ));
    ?>
```

solved but code there if use choice subcategory automatic search,iam want choice use button and form blank ...you have sugestion ?thanks